# No se activa la celda de formulario

Tags: html5, css3

Esto es así: algo está haciendo que no se pueda acceder a la celda del formulario para poder completarla.

- HTML:

```html
!--Ingreso de usuario-->
<form action="" class="loguear">

        
    <div class="usr__data">
        <label for="usuario__id">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="usuario__id" class="logIn__user" placeholder="Usuario" style="text-align: center;">
    </div>

      
     <div class="usr__data"> 

        <label for="usuario__pass" >Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" id="usuario__pass" class="logIn__pass" placeholder="Contraseña" style="text-align: center;">
    </div>
        
    

</form>
```

- CSS:

```css
.loguear {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-end;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
line-height: 45px;
margin-top: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.usr__data {
margin-bottom: -15px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.reg__none {
font-size: 15px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu consulta pero creo que en tu clase '.usr__data' estas poniendo un valor negativo

```css
 .loguear { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-end; justify-content: center; width: 100%; height: 150px; line-height: 45px; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; }
        .usr__data { margin-bottom: 15px; margin-right: 20px; }
        .reg__none { font-size: 15px; margin-right: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="usr__data">
        <label for="usuario__id">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="usuario__id" class="logIn__user" placeholder="Usuario" style="text-align: center;">
    </div>
     <div class="usr__data"> 
        <label for="usuario__pass" >Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" id="usuario__pass" class="logIn__pass" placeholder="Contraseña" style="text-align: center;">
    </div>
```

si ese es tu duda en buena hora si no especifica un poco mas para poder ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Lamento la poca especificidad de mi pregunta.  Mi problema es que, al hacer click en el campo o en la palabra "Usuario" en la pagina, la celda no permite que se pueda acceder (osea, escribir) dentro de ella. Es decir, no se pueden ingresar datos, pero solo en la celda "Usuario", ya que en "Contraseña", si lo permite.